# Finding the function $f(x)$ through the given set of conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, periodic-functions

I got terribly stuck while solving this question recently

Let $f(x)$ be a real valued function such that $$f(0)=\frac{1}{2}; \quad f(x+y) =f(x) f(a-y) +f(y) f(a-x).$$

I do not want the rigorous solution to this problem. I want a possible approach that can be used.

I tried plugging in the values of $0$, $a$, etc but couldn't find the function anyway.

How do I proceed?

EDIT:
a is a constant

Comment: This is a functional equation. In particular one which is similar to the functional equation of the _sine addition formula_.

Comment: Is $a$ arbitrary or is it fixed?

Comment: a is fixed,i.e it is a constant

Comment: @JensSchwaiger Yes it sure does. But how do manipulate it? a is present here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $f(x-y)=f(x)$ in the original equation results in  $f(x+y)=2f(x)f(y)$ or $m(x+y)=m(x)m(y)$ for $m:=2f$. Because of $m(a-x)=m(x)$ (a result contained in the answer by Anurag A) and $m(a)=1$ we get $m(2x)=m(x)^2=1$. What does this imply for $f$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Assuming $a$ is fixed. Set $x=y=0$, to get
$$f(0)=2f(0)f(a).$$
This implies $f(a)=1/2$.
Now just set $y=0$, to get
$$f(x)=f(x)f(a)+f(0)f(a-x) \implies f(x)=f(a-x).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes thanks. However how do i find a trigonometric function by continuing this solution?

Comment: @VAMSIKRISHNACHILAKAMARRI i thought you only want a hint not a "rigorous" solution. Without additional conditions, you cannot say that it has to be a trigonometric solution. Though it certainly is one of the solutions. For example, a constant function $f(x)=1/2$ is also a solution.

Comment: yes i do not want the rigorous solution. I just want to know how to relate from this equation to a trigonometric solution.(which is a possible solution). So I just relate the formulae of addition of sine and cosine functions and see what matches?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I don't see any direct relation to trigonometric function. By the way, the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3677709/229831) by [Jens Schwaiger](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/532419/jens-schwaiger) shows that $ f $ must be constant; i.e. $ f ( x ) = \frac 1 2 $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $.